# Collation won't set when creating new database

Tags: postgresql, collation, postgresql-13

I am trying to set the collation for a new database in PostgreSQL 13 but it does not seem to take effect:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE assets ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \l
                                      List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 assets    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

How can I have the new database reflect my collation changes?

Comment: That cannot happen with PostgreSQL, you'd get an error message...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Right, I'm not sure why my system did not notify me of this. Bizarre...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CREATE DATABASE` statement in the question will copy the new database from  `template1`, the default template database, whose `LC_COLLATE` is `en_US.UTF-8`. Since the new database wants a `C` collation, normally the database creation should fail with this error:

```
CREATE DATABASE assets ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';

ERROR:  new collation (C) is incompatible with the collation of the template database (en_US.UTF-8)
HINT:  Use the same collation as in the template database, or use template0 as template.
```

This is because Postgres doesn't know whether this `template1` database contains objects (indexes, mostly) that rely on `en_US.UTF-8` string ordering. If it blindly copied it into new database with the `C` collation, these indexes would be corrupted.

Aside from the fact that you didn't get that error message (which seems really weird) , the advice in the HINT section of the error is what you need: add **`TEMPLATE 'template0'`** to the options of `CREATE DATABASE`. `template0`, contrary to `template1`, cannot be populated with custom contents, so it's guaranteed to contain only data that is compatible with any collation and encoding supported by Postgres.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So, with using `template0` and the same options mentioned in my question, will I be able to also store data containing characters from other languages? (e.g. `معلومات مثال` and `ダミーデータ`) This is necessary to have in my database. I still want them all to use `C` collation.

Comment: @leetbacoon: yes. The ability to store characters from all languages comes with the UTF8 encoding, and it's compatible with the contents of `template0`.